# What are these parts included with mounting bolts?

Tags: walls, screws, mounting, bolts

I have a thing to mount on the wall. These things were coming with it. To figure out how to apply them properly I has to know how these things and their parts are called.
There 10mm inscription on the yellow sleeve and numbers 12 and 10x60 on the blue.
[image]

Comment: Can you link the pull-up bar?

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica oh, it would be hard for me to find, sorry. I had to struggle to find those model once. Nothing special, just a little wider than most of such.

Comment: What I'm fishing for is, is this an item you found at retail at Sears or REI.... is it a Harbor Freight / Canadian Tire special... or did you get it on eBay/Amazon/Alibaba.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica from some seller on the Internet, not Sears or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Those look like two different kinds of anchors. One for masonry (self-contained with metal sleeve), and the other for drywall (blue sleeves and lag screws).

You'll select the appropriate anchor for the surface you're mounting to and drill an appropriate sized hole. For masonry, you'll insert the entire thing through whatever you're mounting (some type of bracket?), into the hole. For drywall, you'll insert the blue sleeve into the hole, then insert the lag screw through the object to be mounted, into the sleeve.

In either case, tightening the head of the anchor or screw will cause the outer part of the anchor (metal or plastic sleeve) to expand and fit tightly in or behind the hole, securing your object.

Comment: those blue sleeves are not for drywall ... think about how thick drywall is ... i think that they are for concrete or brick

Comment: @jsotola: masonry anchors would work fine for concrete or brick. I can't tell from the photo the dimension of those anchors. And I have seen and even used drywall anchors significantly longer than the 1/2" or 5/8" that is typical in home construction. But, if you have something **constructive** to offer, rather than just a negative comment, I welcome any suggestion that would improve this answer or your own.

Comment: Drywall anchors are designed to spread to form a star or similar.

Comment: @SolarMike: some are, some aren't. Long ones go through the drywall, and expand/spread behind it. Short ones fit in the depth of the drywall and just create friction. The ones in the picture look to me like they probably are the former, but without exact dimensions I'm not confident to say either way. (And just to make things more interesting: the Elfa hanging shelf product from The Container Store  uses drywall anchors that sort of scrunch up behind the drywall, expanding but in a fashion different from the typical anchor).

Comment: the fasteners pictured are both intended for a 10mm (AKA 3/8") hole. (it's written on the blue one)

Comment: @Jasen there numbers 12 and '0x60 on the blue sleeve. And 10mm inscription on the yellow sleeve.

Comment: @Peter Duniho I updated the question. All of those supposed to go in the same type of wall if they're in the same kit, there 4 holes - 4 bolts.

Comment: @RS: _"All of those supposed to go in the same type of wall if they're in the same kit"_ -- what makes you say that? Is there documentation provided with the kit that actually states that explicitly? Because, I _very frequently_ purchase items that come with mounting hardware where there are multiple options for mounting, and only some of the parts are used. What makes you believe that these parts should all be used in conjunction with each other? You really ought to provide 100% of the detail available, including the specifics of the item being mounted and anything else that comes w/ the kit.

Comment: @Peter Duniho because there 4 holes in the thing to be mounted and it shipped with those 4 screws. The thing is pull-up bar.

Comment: @RS: note the ungrooved shank of the plastic sleeves is just over 5/8" or 11/16", exactly what one would expect for a drywall anchor that expands behind the hole. There really is not enough context in your question, but possibly they intend for the masonry anchors to go into a stud (though if so, I'd wonder why not just use a lag screw directly in the wood), and the drywall anchor to go into adjacent drywall. This really seems more like a question the manufacturer would be able to answer more to your liking. I've explained what they are called, which is what you asked.

Comment: @jsotola the whole thing supposed to be mounted onto brick or concrete (it's a pull-up bar) and all those anchors were in the kit with the thing.

Comment: I didn't read the entire squabble above this comment, but I'd never use lag screw anchors in a hollow wall situation. Screws that large need solid substrate, not hollow mush.

Answer (score 1):

If each side of the bar has 2 anchor points I would use the metal sleeve anchors on the top and the plastic ones on bottom. The pullout force is greater on the top position. The bottom is mostly shear force so the plastic would be better on the bottom in a concrete or block wall.

Comment: Totally agree. I read this question this morning but didn't have time to type answer.... Mine would have been similar.  Worked with an electrician in the 60's and he used the blue anchors all the time in block. He said the plastic formed to the crevices in the holes.+