# How to mount these anchors?

Tags: concrete, walls, mounting, anchor

In the mounted object (pull-up bar) there are 4 holes and in the kit there are 4 such anchors.
**One type** has a metal sleeve, there's decent gap between internal bolt and the sleeve - it moves freely, it has nut on the end. 10mm inscription on the sleeve.
**The other** has plastic sleeve with pimples outside, very tight: I can't screw in the screw with hands. Inscriptions: 12 and 10x60.
They going to go into brick/concrete wall. Thought one guy tells that blue ones are drywall anchors.
[image]

There 3 things I would like to clarify:
**1. Sizes of drill bits** 
It seems I need 2 bits.
I've seen a controversial info on the Internet: that the hole should be the same size as the sleeve, also that it should be bigger.

**2. What way I should put them inside** 
Аre sleeves supposed to be inserted with hands or with hammer?
What about internal parts (blue are very tight - may be a hammer)?
**3. Sequencing.**
Metal sleeves seams supposed to widen: entirely or only at the ends? 
Should I insert the sleeve first and then the shaft? With a hammer? One guy told be to [insert the entire thing.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/183684/87316)

Comment: The other guy is absolutely wrong about the blue plastic sleeves. They are *not* drywall anchors. They are for masonry walls.

Comment: I agree with brhans that those aren't drywall anchors.They're  too long.The smooth sleeve it 7/8" long and if installed in drywall, it would pull out 3/8" before catching he spread.

Comment: Seems like this was addressed in the [original question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/183683/what-are-these-details-bolts).

Comment: I'd agree, @isherwood. I was actually thinking a VtC would be appropriate here (once I saw the original), but I don't have the rep for that.

Comment: @FreeMan the first was about terms and this about mounting, I hoped that 2nd will not be necessary. And if still somebody would like to close then, please go for the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are 2 different types of wall anchors.

The blue ones are generally drywall anchors. You drill a hole *just* large enough for the blue plastic sleeve to press-fit in. Usually, you'll need a hammer to gently bang it in the final 1/4" (2-3 mm) - it should be that tight.

You would then line up the mounting hole of the thing to be hung over the center of the exposed hole in the anchor and drive the screw/bolt through it to secure it to the wall. The threads of the bolt (in this case) would bite into the plastic (they'll just strip out a hole in drywall), giving them grip. They'll also expand the plastic to make an even tighter fit against the drywall *and* will mushroom a bit on the inside of the wall making a larger blob of plastic that will resist the pulling forces on the mounted object by spreading them across the inside of the drywall.

---

The gold ones are designed for concrete/cement. Again, you drill a hole just large enough to slip the entire sleeve into. Again, you may need to lightly tap with a hammer to get it all the way home. <s>However, this time, you put the thing to be hung up against the wall *before* inserting the anchor. The "flange" or "washer" attached to the bolt head is what holds the thing-to-be-anchored against the wall.</s> *As noted in @JACK's comment:* Once you've driven it into the wall with the hammer, tighten the nut lightly to hold the sleeve in place in the wall, remove the nut, slip the thing-to-be-hung over the exposed threads, put the nut back on and tighten all the way.

As you tighten the nut, the wedge at the far end is pulled back toward the wall, expanding the sleeve against the inside of the hole and mushrooming the metal inside the hole (or inside the gap if going into a hollow in a concrete block/cinder block).

---

Since you're hanging a pull-up bar on a concrete/block wall, use the concrete anchors. The "10 mm" inscription is *most likely* the size bit you need to drill a clearance hole for the anchor to slip into.

Comment: Pretty good except " flange or washer attached to bolt head" , it's not a bolt but a nut . Insert the anchor into the hole, tap with a hammer, and tighten the nut a bit. Then remove the nut and install the item to be hung and re-install the nut and tighten it home.

Comment: Also, know that for the wedge anchor, you leave the nut on when tapping it into place.  And wedge anchors MUST be used in solid concrete.  The plastic sleeve is a "hollow wall anchor" which includes hollow bricks.  Wedge anchors don't work in hollow blocks.

Comment: @JACK why tight the nut before install and not only once after?

Comment: @RS you tighten a bit to ensure the anchor stays firm in the wall as you back the nut off and hang your "thing" on the threads. If the sleeve isn't snugged up a little bit, the whole thing can move around on you while you're trying to get all your holes lined up over all the moving anchors. Additionally, it ensures that you can focus on getting _this_ anchor properly seated and started without having to worry about supporting the thing being hung while trying to do that.

Comment: @FreeMan  I Could not have said it better.

Comment: @JACK so I have to use 10mm bit for both? Plastic is 12, 10x60. 60 is length, 10 is diameter of most of the sleeve and 12 seems to be diameter with pimples.

Comment: @RS There should be mounting instructions. I would start out with the 10 mm drill based on your info but it might be too small for the plastic.